# How to show an array in the schema of an body with swagger-ui

Tags: arrays, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to document all API requests with swagger-ui and do have the following issue:

The body I need to send via the request is an array of ids

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

To have the schema displayed, the schema-type must be set to array. And this causes the problem, that I do have additional brackets which are not part of the body I need to provide.

```
[
  {
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My swagger.yml is created like described below.
**Is there a possibility to get rid of the brackets so that my schema fits to the body I need  to provide?**

```
paths:
 /elements/remove:
  patch:
   security: ...
   summary: ...
   parameters:
    - name: Body
      in: body
      description: ...
      required: true
      schema:
       $ref: '#deveinitions/Elements'


definitions:
 Element_neseted:
    type: object
    required:
      - id
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
        description: >-
          Id is in request body for update of events.

 Elements:
  type: object
  required:
      - elements
    properties:
      assets:
        type: array
        title: "elements"
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Element_neseted'
```

Comment: changed the /path slightly - but without success...

Comment: the problem is solved, after changing the /path the brackets where still displayed because I need to delete the history / cash of the browser.